# Slow magento site

Tags: php, magento

I created this website for a client using magento 1.9. After a while, it started becoming slow. These are the steps I've taken

- cleaned out the logs
- compressed the javascript and css
- optimized images
- enabled flat catalag and product
- output compression with gzip from apache etc.

The site is a startup and is hosted on a shared hosting server on godaddy. The products there are not upto 200, What else can i do to make it faster? any recommendation?

Comment: First of all: Was it slow after a few hours? Or constantly slower between a few days? And what "slow" we're talking about?
Change to another Framework! I'm just kidding.. Do you use something like apc caching? You really should :) What else to do.. Clear overfilled tables. Like entered search queries by users. I think, that's a really big point.

Comment: @Jahswey Yes, I agree with Tyralcori response above. How slow are your site? Does it happen everyday or only for few hours? There are many factors that make your site slow.

Comment: I'm not usually one to chuck resources at something like this, but, a Magento site on shared hosting? You gotta be kidding me. We have a site running on dual dedicated machines and even that is a touch slow.

Comment: I run mine on 1and1 shared hosting and it's not too bad. I use Lesti FPC and it's pretty good.

Comment: Yeah, Magento is a real beast, running it on bog standard shared hosting is a bit of a faux pas, it's a serious ecommerce platform for stores that are successful and willing to allocate a sizeable budget for hosting alone. If you're just selling a few products I'd opt for something a little less resourceful. In saying that if you're hell bent on using it there are some fantastic Full Page Caching extensions available. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc-simple-fullpagecache.html being one.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments, it takes over 20secs just to load the page most times 15 secs and its like this everyday. When I first launched it, it used to be fast.

Comment: That is slow! Are you using cron to clear out your logs etc every night?

Comment: Hi PedroKTFC, I don't have log enabled on my backend

Comment: Check your database backup size. I back mine up every night and originally found it was getting bigger each night. I found user visits were getting logged in there and limited the number of days they'd be stored for. You might unwittingly be logging something.

Comment: Hi PedroKTFC, I just backed up the database and downloaded it, it's not upto 2mb, I don't think it's log files cos I don't have it enabled

Comment: Was just a suggestion. Have you looked at webpagetest to see if there's anything in particular that's slow?